# Twilio International SMS

Tags: twilio

Im building a C# .Net financial app that notifies users using SMS. I have implemented the Twilio Rest API SMS and this works fine when i deploy on our local servers in Nigeria. When I deploy to our test servers in the US, I cannot send SMS to any Nigerian Number. Hope someone can help

I have purchased 2 numbers from twilio and  enabled Nigeria on the permissions page.

Hope someone can help

Comment: Hi, Twilio Evangelist here. Please send an email to help@twilio.com and they should be able to assist you with this.

Comment: I have done that before I posted here. Help seems to be slow in coming. It takes sometime before they reply. I wish they had online chat support like IBM Softlayer. At least you can chat with support staffs realtime and they only refer you when its a big technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

International numbers can't SMS the USA. I was running into the same problem and found the answer in small print on [these docs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183068-Twilio-international-phone-number-availability-and-their-capabilities#toll_free)

Answer (score 0):

Please contact the Twilio support. They shall able to guide you. They must have enabled some carriers to deliver messages to Nigeria numbers. They shall enable the ones you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your SMS settings here

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international/sms

To view and edit your international settings

Comment: I had that enabled already. That's why SMS can be sent on my localhost. it only fails when I deploy the solution to our test servers in the US. All the same thanks

Comment: I've done the same. Checked them all off. Still not working.